# Neighbourhoods of $\mathbf{1}$ within the weak topology

Tags: general-topology, weak-topology

Consider a weak topological space.

I am trying to show or explain why that for every weak neighbourhood $N$ of $\mathbf{1}$, there is a finite set of vectors such that $N$ contains every vector $\mathbf{x}$ with the condition $$|\langle \mathbf{x-1}, \mathbf{b}\rangle| < 25$$

Does this just follow from the definition of the weak topology/weak convergence?

Comment: It seems your question does not involve $e_n$ or $S$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you introduce the set $S$... maybe you also wanted to ask a different question.

In any case, yes, as you anticipate, the weak topology has a local *sub* -basis of sets $U_{x,\epsilon}=\{v\in \ell^2: |\langle v,x\rangle|<\epsilon\}$. Then the local *basis* consists of finite intersections of these, which are as you've indicated.

Comment: Ahh okay, just wanted to double check. I think the S set is used in the other part of the problem, I just wanted to make sure my understanding of the weak topology was correct and I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the sub-basis (and thus finite intersections to obtain the basis), are they all possible intersections of the elements of the sub-basis or all possible intersections of any subset generated from the sub-basis?

Comment: @CraigLutic, yes, that's a very relevant question... and the answer is that they are both the same. Not so hard to prove. :)

Comment: Ahh I just thought about it haha it'd give you exactly the same thing. Thanks again!

Comment: All possible **finite** intersections of elements of the subbasis.